# Powershell GUI. Selecting an item from a dynamic ListBox with subsequent unloading of user information from Active Directory Ask a question

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory, listbox

Good afternoon, dear forum users. Please help me with the next question. I am trying to create a GUI application in Powershell GUI. Since I am a beginner in programming and knowledge, I have not decided to contact the forum for help. The essence of the application is to search by full name in the Active Directory accounts of the required employee account and view the date the password was changed for this account.
I have a ready-made code that works when entering an account login in English. At the same time, I want to implement a search in Russian. The code that I give below searches in Russian, but only in text form displays a list of accounts by name, this text can only be copied. I ask you to tell me how you can program the program so that it searches not in the form of text, full name, but in the form of elements on whose name you can click with the mouse cursor and get the result. I attach a screenshot of the program https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ5qP.png. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(460,350) # Mold size
$Form.Text ="Pass info"
$Form.AutoSize = $false
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false # button expand program
$Form.MinimizeBox = $true # minimize program button
$Form.BackColor = "#c08888" # Form color
$Form.ShowIcon = $true # Enable icon (upper left corner) $ true, disable icon
$Form.SizeGripStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle]::Hide # Prevent form stretching
#$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D # Prevent form stretching _2
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen
$Form.Opacity = 1.0 # Form transparency
$Form.TopMost = $false # 
Over other windows


########### Function start:

function Info {
$wks=$InputBox.text;
Write-Host $wks
$regex1 = "[^-a-zA-Z0-9_#.!@]+"
$regex2 = "[^-а-яА-Я0-9_#.!@]+"
If($wks -match $regex2) {
$Result1=Get-ADUser -identity $wks -Properties * | select CN -ExpandProperty CN
$outputBox.text=$Result1
$Result2=Get-ADUser -identity $wks -Properties * | select PasswordLastset -ExpandProperty PasswordLastset
$outputBox2.text=$Result2
}
If($wks -match $regex1) { 
$wks2 = "$wks*"
Write-Host $wks2
$Result3=Get-AdUser -Filter 'name -Like $wks2' | Select Name -expandproperty Name| Sort Name | fl | out-string
Write-Host $Result3 

#$Result3 = ($Result3 -replace ' ','_')
#$Result3 = $Result3 -split '_',2 -join ' '
$ListBox.text = $Result3
} 
}

########### End Function.


############################################## Start text fields

#### Group selection of labels 2 and 3$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,230)
$groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,80)
$groupBox.text = "Info:"
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)

$FormLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$FormLabel1.Text = "User AD:"
$FormLabel1.ForeColor = "#3009f1"
$FormLabel1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,8"
$FormLabel1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$FormLabel1.AutoSize = $true
$Form.Controls.Add($FormLabel1)

$FormLabel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$FormLabel2.Text = "ФИО:"
$FormLabel2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,25)
$FormLabel2.ForeColor = "#3009f1"
$FormLabel2.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,8"
$FormLabel2.AutoSize = $true
#$Form.Controls.Add($FormLabel2) # Метка явл. частью общ. Form
$groupBox.Controls.Add($FormLabel2) # Метка явл. частью groupBox

$FormLabel3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$FormLabel3.Text = "Дата:"
$FormLabel3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,47)
$FormLabel3.ForeColor = "#3009f1"
$FormLabel3.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,8"
$FormLabel3.AutoSize = $true
#$Form.Controls.Add($FormLabel3) # Метка явл. частью общ. Form
$groupBox.Controls.Add($FormLabel3) # Метка явл. частью groupBox

############################################ InputBox #########################################

$InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(65,5)
$InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox)

$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20)
$outputBox.ReadOnly = $True 
$groupBox.Controls.Add($outputBox)

$outputBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$outputBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,42)
$outputBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,42)
$outputBox2.ReadOnly = $True 
$groupBox.Controls.Add($outputBox2)

############################################## ListBox

$ListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$ListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(65,30) 
$ListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,200) 
$ListBox.MultiLine = $True #declaring the text box as multi-line 
$ListBox.AcceptsReturn = $true
$ListBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$ListBox.AcceptsTab = $true
$ListBox.WordWrap = $True
$ListBox.ReadOnly = $True

$Form.Controls.Add($ListBox)

############################################## End ListBox 


############################################## search in Russian and in English

$regex1 = "[^-a-zA-Z0-9_#.!@]+"
$regex2 = "[^-а-яА-Я0-9_#.!@]+"
$TestName = "Mouse" # Mouse или мышь
If($TestName -match $regex1){echo "English '$TestName'"}
If($TestName -match $regex2){echo "Русский '$TestName'"}
get-aduser -filter 'name -like "*" ' | select name -expandproperty name

############################################## End search in Russian and in English

################  Button

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,20)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,80)
$Button.Text = "Загрузить данные"
$Button.BackColor = "#d7f705"
$Button.Add_Click({Info})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

################ End Button

################ Binding a button in the program to the Enter key on the keyboard ...
$Form.KeyPreview = $True
$Form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {
    # if enter, perform click
    $Button.PerformClick()
    }
})
################ End Binding a button

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hi you can add you aduser info to a DataGridView  $mDataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView $mDataGrid1.add_CellContentDoubleClick($Selectuser) and use de value $selectetuser in your input txt  for datagridview look internet how you can do that

Comment: Kemal K. Thanks for the answer. I understand that instead of $ ListBox, use $ mDataGrid1?
I tried that, but it doesn't work either. I attach the code and screenshot.

Comment: https://funkyimg.com/view/3ak6p

Answer (score 0):

This is some example how is works:

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $MyForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $MyForm.Text = "USER info Lastlogondate"
    $MyForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 500)

    #user info 
    $allinfo=$null
    #change your domin info
    $allinfo=Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=users,DC=domain,DC=local" -properties Name, SamAccountName,Lastlogondate

    #select in the column user name to fill $mTextBox1.Text
    $Selectuser = 
    {    
        $c = $mDataGrid1.CurrentCell.columnindex
        $colHeader = $mDataGrid1.columns[$c].name
        if ($colHeader -eq "SamAccountName") {
            $username = $mDataGrid1.CurrentCell.Value
            $mTextBox1.Text = $username
            Write-Host $username

        }
    } #

    #usernema textbox--------------------------------------------     
    $mTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $mTextBox1.Text = ""
    $mTextBox1.Top = "20"
    $mTextBox1.Left = "26"
    $mTextBox1.Anchor = "Left,Top"
    $mTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 23)
    $MyForm.Controls.Add($mTextBox1)

    #gridview
    $mDataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    $mDataGrid1.Text = "DataGrid1"
    $mDataGrid1.Top = "60"
    $mDataGrid1.Left = "27"
    $mDataGrid1.Anchor = "Left,Top"    
    $mDataGrid1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 16  
    $mDataGrid1.add_CellContentDoubleClick($Selectuser)               
    $mDataGrid1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 330)
    $MyForm.Controls.Add($mDataGrid1)

    #GetAllUsers button------------------------------------------
    $mButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $mButton1.Text = "Get All Users"
    $mButton1.Top = "20"
    $mButton1.Left = "200"
    $mButton1.Anchor = "Left,Top"
    $mButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 23)        
    $MyForm.Controls.Add($mButton1)
    $mButton1.Add_Click( {  GetAllusers})


    Function GetAllusers {
        $mDataGrid1.DataSource = $null
        $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList    
        $result=$allinfo |Select-Object Name, SamAccountName,Lastlogondate|sort -Property Name            
        $array.Addrange($result) 
        $mDataGrid1.Datasource = ($array) 
        $MyForm.Refresh()      
    }

    #exit---------------------------------------------------------      

    $mButton4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $mButton4.Text = "Exit"
    $mButton4.Top = "20"
    $mButton4.Left = "320"
    $mButton4.Anchor = "Left,Top"
    $mButton4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120, 23)
    $mButton4.Add_Click( {$MyForm.Close()})
    $MyForm.Controls.Add($mButton4)

    $MyForm.ShowDialog()
```